# Cannot delete rows from a table SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, delete-row

I am writing a query to delete some rows in my table based on the count (TOTALCOUNT). I would like to delete all rows that count <=5. Below is my query:

```
DELETE  FROM NSFABSTRACTS WHERE TOTALCOUNT<=5
  SELECT WORD, COUNT(WORD) AS TOTALCOUNT FROM NSFABSTRACTS
  GROUP BY WORD;
```

I also tried the one below, didn't work either:

```
DELETE  FROM NSFABSTRACTS 
  SELECT WORD, COUNT(WORD) AS TOTALCOUNT FROM NSFABSTRACTS
  GROUP BY WORD
WHERE TOTALCOUNT<=5;
```

It is giving me this error:

`Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:

*Action:`.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE  FROM NSFABSTRACTS 
WHERE WORD IN (
                SELECT WORD FROM NSFABSTRACTS
                GROUP BY WORD
                HAVING COUNT(*)<=5
              )
```

This removes all those rose containing words which occur less than equal to 5 times in table.

Comment: This works! One follow up question, I also want to write the total count of every word in the table.How do I do I do that?

Comment: do u want to display count or store it in new table ?..what is the table structure..?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DELETE  FROM NSFABSTRACTS 
WHERE FileID IN
(
  SELECT FILEID
  FROM NSFABSTRACTS 
  GROUP BY WORD, FILEID
  HAVING COUNT(WORD) <=5;
)
```

Assuming file ID is your primary key.

Comment: FileID is not my primary key. I am counting how many times a word shows up in a list of files rather than one. And what I want to delete are those show up in all files less than 5.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DELETE  FROM NSFABSTRACTS 
WHERE FILEID IN
(
     SELECT FILEID FROM NSFABSTRACTS
     GROUP BY FILEID, WORD
     HAVING COUNT(Word)<=5
)
```

Comment: FILEID is not my primary key. I am counting word numbers from all files, they might from the same or different files. I just want to remove the words that show up less than 5 times in the whole pool rather than a single file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
delete from NSFabstracts where fileID in 
(select fileid from nsfabstracts group by word,fileid
having COUNT(word)<=5)
```